# Apache AGE- Get all Edges

Tags: apache-age

I'm using the Apache AGE extension, I have a graph named `Family` with a vertex named `PERSON`. And many edges such as `CHILD_OF`, `GRANDCHILD_OF`, `UNCLE_OF`, `AUNT_OF`.
Now what I want is to display all the edges present in the graph.
I can get the Vertices using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Family', $$
MATCH (a)
RETURN a
```

This would list down all the vertices and their properties.
I want to do the same with edges, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display all the edges you can use the `MATCH` clause as

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Family', $$
MATCH (a)-[e]->(b)
RETURN e
```

Now if you want to put a filter on which edge to display based on label, you can do as

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('Family', $$
MATCH (a)-[e: CHILD_OF]->(b)
RETURN e
```

Read about MATCH clause in the [doc](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/match.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command.

```
SELECT * from "Family"._ag_label_edge;
```

This will return a table with a list of all the edges with their properties.

You can use a similar command for vertices also.

```
SELECT * from "Family"._ag_label_vertex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Match all the edges by the following format:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM cypher('Family', $$
      MATCH (a1:PERSON)-[r:<edge_label>]->(a2:PERSON)
      RETURN type(r)
    $$) as (r agtype);
```

"edge_label" can be CHILD_OF, GRANDCHILD_OF, UNCLE_OF, AUNT_OF any of them.